# Unable to upload files to AWS S3 buckets using CORS

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, sinatra

I was just trying out the example which is specified in this blog, but I am getting this error "Could not contact signing script. Status = 404". I followed all the steps specified in the blog and also carefully changed the CORS configuration in AWS management Console too. I am not able to figure out the problem. Kindly help me out.

Here is the blog link http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1539/direct-browser-uploading-amazon-s3-cors-fileapi-xhr2-and-signed-puts/

Comment: Which blog? You've got no links in your question.

Comment: We definitely need more info here. But a 404 is definitely not a S3 CORS or policy problem (in which case you would (and you will ;)) get a 400). My guess is that your upload script is making a request to a signing script to sign your key secret, and this script is not found

Comment: Can you share link to blog ? or your policy and request code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem you did trying to follow the example in this blog post. I wrote an article showing everything I had to do to make it work for me.

https://blog.pjam.me/posts/direct-upload-to-s3/

Hope it'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this today and comment on your blog.

Comment: At the moment it lacks a live demo, but I'll make one soon.

Comment: awesome I guess that will lot of people actually

Comment: @pjam Please update the link given in your answer: https://blog.pjam.me/posts/direct-upload-to-s3/